# I need some help to solve this problem with my opencv program please?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv for a project which displays an image and after you close the displayed image, that same image will open as well as a new additional image. The code is below but it is only displaying one image and not 2.

```
import cv2
import time
import random
import os

k = 0
rep = 0
window_name = "Monkey Virus"
files = os.listdir("Z:\Y10 Python\images wow\img")
delay = random.randint(0,10)
monkeyChoice = random.randint(1,len(files))
image = "Z:\\Y10 Python\\images wow\\img\\" + str(monkeyChoice) + ".jpg"
monkeyHist = 1

def draw_img():
    global monkeyHist
    if rep == 0:
        time.sleep(delay)
    monkeyHist += 1
    img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

draw_img()
rep = rep + 1

if cv2.getWindowProperty('Monkey Virus', cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
    while k < monkeyHist:
        draw_img()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `cv2.imshow(...)` followed by `cv2.waitKey(0)` on the main thread. Therefore, after the first call, the thread will be blocked and no further code will be executed until the user presses a key. If you want to show a second image, you need to call `cv2.imshow()` again with a different window_name argument before the call to `cv2.waitKey(0)`.

(Also

```
while k < monkeyHist:
    draw_img()
```

is probably an endless loop, as your `draw_img()` function only ever increases monkeyHist, but never increases k; therefore, k is forever smaller than monkeyHist.)